workflow_run skips the workflow if the previous workflow fails
UPD: the problem was in "if" condition which checks if previous workflow succeeds in build_and_run.yaml which my partner wrote without me noticing it long time ago. A stupid mistake
I have 2 workflows formatting.yaml and build_and_run.yaml. Build_and_run has workflow_run which runs when formatting is completed. Formatting has 3 jobs in it and when 2 jobs out of 3 fail, the whole workflow has "Failure" status. It used to work fine just a week or 2 ago, but now for some reason when the formatting workflow fails, the build_and_run just skips. I don't understand why that happens as I am using "workflow_run" and type "completed" and nothing else which would result in build_and_run being skipped.
formatting.yaml
name: Formatting Check and Fix

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  formatting-check:
    ...

  check-formatting-validation-result:
    ...

  formatting-fix:
    ...

build_and_run.yaml
name: Build and Run

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: [Formatting Check and Fix]
    types:
      - completed

jobs:
  build-and-run:
    ...

example of skipped run when formatting workflow failed: 
formatting - failure
build_and_run - skipped
example of a run, where formatting workflow succeeded and build_and_run wasn't skipped: 
formatting - success
build_and_run - not skipped
here are the links to the actual workflows:
formatting workflow, build_and_run workflow
What i want is for build_and_run to be executed after formatting workflow completes. That's all. I don't want build_and_run to execute only if formatting succeeds or only if it fails, i just want it to run when formatting finished regardless of its result.
Just wanted to point that out.

Just to be sure, is the build_and_run workflow also skipped when using if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'failure' }} in the first job condition? (it may be skipped due to this condition)

@GuiFalourd Omg, this is such a dumb mistake for me. My friend added this line without me noticing it long time ago and i couldn't notice it for almost a week! Thank you so much and this is just funny and absurd.
Offtopic: it is like that situation when you can't find something and call someone to help you and then you notice this item yourself immediately standing at the most obvious spot.

No problem, everybody has already been there :) I will add an official answer then.

Checking your build_and_run workflow file:
name: Build and Run

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: [Formatting Check and Fix]
    types:
      - completed

jobs:
  build-and-run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}
    steps:
      ...


This condition if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }} is the reason your workflow is skipped when the first workflow failed. The workflow will only run if the triggered workflow is completed successfully, which is not the case here.
If you want it to run on failure, you should use if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'failure' }}.
If you want it to always run, just remove the condition and the workflow will be executed every time the trigger workflow is completed (with success or failure).
